# Acceder a Pdf en un servidor red

Tags: html5, pdf

Buena tarde estoy tratando de acceder a un pdf que esta en un servidor, puedo tener acceso a el por medio del navegador pero cuando lo llamo por medio de html no carga alguna idea, ya jale el pdf hacia mi pc y si lo puedo consultar
se los agradezco

```
<%
            String pdf = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("pdf"));
            %>

                       
 <iframe src="<%= pdf %>" style="width:100%; height:1000px;" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

estoy recibiendo una variable (pdf)con la dirección, pero si trae la url del servidor en red no me muestra el pdf si yo pongo una direccion de mi pc si lo hace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un `iframe` o bien un `object`.

**Iframe**

```
<iframe id="fred" style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="PDF in an i-Frame" src="PDFData.pdf" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="1100" width="850" ></iframe>
```

**object**

```
<object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
  <embed src="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero el problema, esque si puedo acceder al archivo por medio del navegador pero cuando pongo la url en el src no me despliega nada

Comment: por favor pon tu código para poder ver que estas implementando, vuelve a editar tu pregunta e introduce tu código.

Comment: ya lo actualice

Comment: Fíjate en el código fuente que te genera, fíjate si te da bien la ruta o si está con el formato final .pdf

Comment: estuve leyendo que no el navegador no puede acceder a una posicion que no este dentro del proyecto... por ejemplo C:Documents

Comment: ah claro, pensé que eso ya lo tenias claro, Tenes que crear una carpeta en la `raíz` de tu proyecto ejemplo llamado `pdf`, y si tu archivo se encuentra también en la `raíz` de tu proyecto creas una `url` para llamar a tu `pdf` ejemplo `pdf/archivo.pdf`. si lo subes a un `servidor` te va a quedar `tuweb.com/pdf/archivo.pdf`. te dejo este [enlace](https://aprende-web.net/html/html3_2.php) para que leas un poco mas sobre el tema.